# How do I add a Confirm Component to an existing Navigation Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an existing Navigation Component in my React program which has onClicks to "host," "join," and "logout," and I want to add a Confirm Component to the "logout" portion which confirms if the user really wants to logout or not. 
This is the Navigation portion of the code:

```
export default class Navigation extends Component {
  state = { activeItem: 'home' };

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name });

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <Segment inverted>
        <Menu inverted pointing secondary>
          <Menu.Item
            as={Link}
            to='/'
            name='home'
            active={activeItem === 'home'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            as={Link}
            to='/host'
            name='host'
            active={activeItem === 'host'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            as={Link}
            to='/join'
            name='join'
            active={activeItem === 'join'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            as={Link}
            to='/logout'
            name='logout'
            active={activeItem === 'logout'}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
          />
        </Menu>
      </Segment>
```

*react.semantic-ui.com* has this block of code to implement a Confirm Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Confirm } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class ConfirmExampleConfirm extends Component {
  state = { open: false }

  open = () => this.setState({ open: true })
  close = () => this.setState({ open: false })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.open}>Show</Button>
        <Confirm
          open={this.state.open}
          onCancel={this.close}
          onConfirm={this.close}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ConfirmExampleConfirm
```

Any idea how I can add this into my Navigation Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah a simple way to create a modal in React is to use [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). It allows you to render an element on top of everything else (like for a modal). Then, use your state in your parent container to control whether it's shown/hidden and what the outcome is as a result of cancel/confirming logout.

LogoutConfirmation.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

export const LogoutConfirmation = ({ isOpen, cancel, close}) => {

  if(isOpen) {
    return createPortal(
      <Confirm
        open={isOpen}
        onCancel={cancel}
        onConfirm={close}
      />,
      document.body
    );

  return null;
};
```

Navigation.js

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      activeItem: 'home',
      logoutModalIsOpen: false
    };
  }

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name });

  toggleLogoutModal = () => {
    this.setState({ logoutModalIsOpen: !this.state.logoutModalIsOpen });
  }

  confirmLoggingOut = () => {
    this.state({ logoutModalIsOpen: false, activeItem: 'logout' });

    // if using react-router, you can programatically change the app's
    // url to /logout like you have with your like with this code
    this.props.history.push('/logout');
  }

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Segment inverted>
          <Menu inverted pointing secondary>
            <Menu.Item
              as={Link}
              to='/'
              name='home'
              active={activeItem === 'home'}
              onClick={this.handleItemClick}
            />
            <Menu.Item
              as={Link}
              to='/host'
              name='host'
              active={activeItem === 'host'}
              onClick={this.handleItemClick}
            />
            <Menu.Item
              as={Link}
              to='/join'
              name='join'
              active={activeItem === 'join'}
              onClick={this.handleItemClick}
            />
            <Menu.Item
              as={Button}
              name='logout'
              active={activeItem === 'logout'}
              onClick={this.toggleLogoutModal}
            />
          </Menu>
        </Segment>
        <LogoutConfirmation
          isOpen={this.state.logoutModalIsOpen}
          cancel={this.toggleLogoutModal}
          close={this.confirmLoggingOut}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, technogeek1995!

Comment: Just to "confirm" (ha!), that line `this.props.history.push('logout');` isn't necessary, correct?

Comment: Right. That's only if you're using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) and want to programmatically change the URL to `/logout`.

Comment: Nice approach however, removing the `isOpen` prop and wrapping the component in a shortcut gives the same effect with one less prop and less code in the modal. E.g {this.state.logoutModalIsOpen && <LogoutConfirmation ... />} then remove the null check from modal component.

Answer (score 0):

You could control the confirm dialog from your Navigation component, like this:

```
state = { activeItem: "home", showConfirm: false };
```

Then for the CANCEL and OK actions you could handle with this:

```
closeDialog = () => this.setState({ showConfirm: false });

confirmDialog = () => {
    if (this.state.activeItem === "logout") {
      console.log("Logging out...");
      this.setState({ showConfirm: false });
    }
  };
```

For that to work, you would need to insert your new ConfirmDialog component in your Navigation render:

```
 <ConfirmDialog
      open={this.state.showConfirm}
      cancel={this.closeDialog}
      confirm={this.confirmDialog}
    />
```

Your ConfirmDialog would expect these props from your Navigation and act on them:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Confirm } from "semantic-ui-react";

class ConfirmDialog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Confirm
          open={this.props.open}
          onCancel={this.props.cancel}
          onConfirm={this.props.confirm}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ConfirmDialog;
```

In the end, your code would like this this (click the button):

[image: Edit festive-leftpad-2hrvr]